# Hibernate Mapping when foreign key placed in reference class

Tags: java, hibernate, relationship, one-to-one

I have two classes `Student` and `Address`.

```
Student{
 stuid,
 stuName,
}

Address{
 street,
 city,
 stuid;//foriegn key Ref with Studnet
}
```

Can any one help me to map these two classes using hibernate??

Answer (score 0):

You should learn what is OneToOne mapping in hibernate firstly.
Secondly if I would want to design then I would have address_id as foreign key in Student table and not student id.

//Table name will be taken as Student as you are not specifying it using @Table annotation

**Student class**

```
@Entity
public class Student{

  @Id
  @Column("stuid")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Integer id;

  @Column("stuName")
  private String name;

  //setters and getters

}
```

**Address class**

```
  @Entity
  public class Address{

  @Id
  @Column("add_id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Integer id;

  @Column("street")
  private String street;

  @Column("city")
  private String city;

  @OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.SAVE,CascadeType.MERGE})
  @JoinColumn(name="stuid")
  private Student student

  //setters and getters

}
```

Comment: yes you are correct. but some one already designed my DB. They designed stuid in Address table. That is the main problem here

Comment: So answer contains mapping according to them

Answer (score 0):

Suppose if a `Student` can have multiple `Address` entities then you need to have `one-to-many` relationship between Student and Address classes. A student should know what addresses they belong to and also as you need to save the student id in address table then the relationship becomes bi-directional.

The entities looks like this:

**Student.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student_tbl") // Optional, By default table name is student, if you want to give different name then use this line.
public class Student1 {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int stuid;
    private String stuName;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    private List<Address> address = new ArrayList<Address>();

    // Setters & Getters
}
```

**Address.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "address_tbl")
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int addressId;
    private String street;
    private String city;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="stuid")
    private Student1 student;
    // Setters & Getters
}
```